# Instant app and GDPR

Tags: android-instant-apps

I imagine that even instant apps must be compliant with the GDPR and then show the privacy policy and ask the user for explicit permission to profiling and processing data.

Do I have to show the views needed to ask user consent every time the instant app is opened? 
Is there a way to persist the data the first time so as not to show the screens all the other times?

Comment: I imagine the policy applies to it just like any other normal app, but are you looking for some kind of cookie/shared preferences to store a flag to know if the user has opened your instant app before? See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/cookie-api or https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/storage-api

Comment: yes, exactly, I'm looking for a mechanism that allows to save values to be used in consecutive openings of the same instant app. So not to begin each opening with a "first visit" status.